# Use an option from select to populate a form

Tags: javascript, html

I have a select with multiple options and a form below with an empty text input.
I want the text input to change whenever I change the select but still be updatable. Is it possible?

```
<select name="title" form="updating"  onChange="document.getElementById('selectedValue').innerHTML = this.value;">
 .....
<form action="update.php" id="updating">
  Article Title:<br>
  <input type="text" name="article_title" id=selectedValue>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: want you from only javascript or jquery also fine

Comment: Where you want to update in drop down or in the text box

Comment: If the answer are OK kindly click do the up vote

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you're looking for. With JQuery you can easily use the "on change" function.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#mySelect').change(function() {
    $('#myInput').val($(this).val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="mySelect">
  <option value="Element 1">Element 1</option>
  <option value="Element 2">Element 2</option>
  <option value="Element 3">Element 3</option>
</select>
<br/>
<input type="text" id="myInput" value="" />
```

If you need some more specific function please be more specific also with your question

Comment: Look at the snippet: `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

But i suggest you to open the link and save this remote file as a local file.

Comment: Got it! thank you very much exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

check the [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/0a926rnj/1/)

You can use the jquery cdn before end of the `</head>` tag

Here is the cdn [LINK](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-alpha1/jquery.min.js)